# How can I save Android photos in the WebP format?

Tags: camera, files

[WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?csw=1) images are [at least 20% smaller](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery2).

Windows can open WebP images after installing the [WebP codec](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/webp_codec).

Comment: I don't think there is a camera app that directly converts the format as WebP. And I don't find any converter app on Android either. Anyway, [WebP is only supported from Android 4.0+ officially](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core), so the non-portability might be the reason why there is nothing useful at the moment.

Comment: I am using Android 4.3 - do you know if [Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera) can work with WebP (as it is for 4.4+ only) ?

Comment: No, there is no setting to change format in Google Camera. Everything is in JPG.

Answer (score 1):

**[Open Camera](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencamera/) added WebP support in [version 1.45 (2019/01/14)](https://opencamera.org.uk/history.html).**

It can be set from Settings - Photo Settings - Image format - WebP.

However, from [the official help page](https://opencamera.org.uk/help.html#settings), it should be noted that:

> WebP - This is an alternative (lossy) file format to JPEG. It offers smaller file sizes, but saving takes longer, and some applications may not support WebP images. *Note that WebP images are generated by converting from a JPEG with 100% quality (since the Android camera API does not have native WebP output).*

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

There was also a remark by the developer on [a discussion for "WEBP Support"](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/discussion/general/thread/4b205f17/#4b96) back in 2016:

> Unfortunately this isn't straightforward, as the camera driver will only output JPEG or (if supported) RAW. Converting from JPEG means it's already lossy (I support one could set 100% and convert, but that doesn't necessarily mean lossy AFAIK, just minimal compression). Converting from RAW could work, but requires adding support to decode/convert RAW images so is a fair bit of work (Android's RAW support is only for getting the files from the camera API, and saving them).